# Ajax Post does not load the page, even though the log shows the call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, post

I have two pages in my django app.
 (This is my first django app and I am new to javascript also.)

first page - a table with a checkbox in each row and an edit button
second page - input screen with save button

issue: I am trying to get a list of row-ids from first page to second page

So far:
In the OnClick event of edit button, I collect all the Ids for the selected rows in an array.

I use $.ajax call to send this array to second page through POST.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/secondpage/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: {'idsList': JSON.stringify(selectedIds)},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR " + xhr.status + " - " + thrownError);
        }                        
      });
```

After selecting some rows in first page when I click the the Edit button, 
I see in the django log the following entry
`[13/Aug/2020 14:36:14] "POST /secondpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 41403`
but secondpage does not load. I still see the first page in the browser.

And in the Dev. Tools I see 'success' as last console message.

What am I missing? Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Forgot to add this in the initial post:

```
def secondpage(request):

    idsList = request.POST.getlist('idsList[]')

    return render(request, "secondpage.html", {'listIds': idsList})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending an ajax call to `secondpage/`. There is nothing to tell it to load in the browser. You need to do one of a few choices:

1. get the results from the POST response, and load that result into `pageone', in place
2. Redirect the user to `/secondpage/some/variable/values`, have `def secondpage()` do the calcs, then render `secondpage.html`

**UPDATE AFTER OP EDIT:**

You are not using ajax properly.  With ajax, you stay on the current page (url).  It goes out and fetches some values from the backend (server) and updates the page it is currently on.  What you are doing is sending the request to a new view.  It is returning a complete web page that you aren't doing anything with.

You probably want to just use a form:

```
<form action="/secondpage" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" />
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="go to page 2" />
</form>
```

Then assemble the checked values into a list in the view.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the code for the view to the post.

Comment: See edited answer, using `<form>`.  You already have the form. Use it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I need the list to be passed to the second page when the edit button is clicked on the first page. Can you suggest a way to do that? TIA

Comment: And have the user redirected to `/secondpage`?  Show the code for the form and edit button